# How can I put individual elements of a list into nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested

How can I take a list in the form of:

```
hostnames = ['Pam: 5, 10, 4', Pet: 3, 2', 'Sara: 44, 40, 50']
```

and convert it into a form like :

```
   hostnames = [[pam,5, 10, 4], [Pet,3, 2], [Sara,44, 40, 50]]
```

the end goal is so the code can print something like:

```
 [[pam,5, 10, 4], [Pet,3, 2], [Sara,44, 40, 50]]
 pam has scores of 5, 10 ,4
 pet has scores of 3, 2
 sara has scores of 44, 40, 50
```

my current code to help is this:

```
pos = 0
for var in hostnames:
    newlist = hostnames[pos]
    newlist = [newlist]
    pos = pos + 1
    names = newlist[0]
    print(newlist)
```

I know the code asks for changes made to a new list, but I want this change made to the old `hostname` list. Without using the .Split Function

Comment: There are some typos in your first snippet.

Comment: I noticed that you were using indexing to add to the index you retrieve from the hostnames list. You could just delete the pos variable and change the third line to: newlist = hostnames[var]

Comment: I want to make these changes to the old list, not new but this is the code I could come up with? anyone have a code to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you need to use `str.split` method to split the strings; first split on `:` to separate "key"; then again on `,` to separate the integers:

```
out = []
for var in hostnames:
    k,v = var.split(':')
    out.append([k, *map(int, v.split(','))])
```

Output:

```
[['Pam', 5, 10, 4], ['Pet', 3, 2], ['Sara', 44, 40, 50]]
```

---

Perhaps you're looking for something along the lines of:

```
out = []
for var in hostnames:
    i = var.find(':')
    out.append([var[:i], var[i+2:]])
print(out)

for i, *rest in out:
    print("{} has scores of {}".format(i, *rest))
```

Output:

```
[['Pam', '5, 10, 4'], ['Pet', '3, 2'], ['Sara', '44, 40, 50']]
Pam has scores of 5, 10, 4
Pet has scores of 3, 2
Sara has scores of 44, 40, 50
```

---

If you want to separate integers as well, you could use a nested loop:

```
out = []
for var in hostnames:
    i = var.find(':')
    k, nums = var[:i], var[i+2:]
    tmp = [[]]
    for x in nums:
        if x==',':
            tmp[-1] = int(''.join(tmp[-1]))
            tmp.append([])
        else:
            tmp[-1].append(x)
    tmp[-1] = int(''.join(tmp[-1]))
    out.append([k, *tmp])
    print("{} has scores of {}".format(k, nums))
print(out)
```

Comment: instead of .split can we use .find/splicing function?

Comment: is there a way we can print [['Pam', 5, 10, 4], ['Pet', 3, 2], ['Sara', 44, 40, 50]]

Comment: I want to format this list: hostnames = ['Pam: 5, 10, 4', Pet: 3, 2', 'Sara: 44, 40, 50']

Comment: so it can print like this: [['Pam', '5, 10, 4'], ['Pet', '3, 2'], ['Sara', '44, 40, 50']]

Comment: so yes! instead of 5, 10, 4, we want '5, 10, 4'

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution is the following:

```
hostnames = ['Pam: 5, 10, 4', 'Pet: 3, 2', 'Sara: 44, 40, 50']

out = [_.split(": ") for _ in hostnames]
print(out)

for item in out:
    print(f'{item[0]} has scores of {item[1]}')
```

Prints

```
[['Pam', '5, 10, 4'], ['Pet', '3, 2'], ['Sara', '44, 40, 50']]
Pam has scores of 5, 10, 4
Pet has scores of 3, 2
Sara has scores of 44, 40, 50
```

Comment: I like this @enke code: for var in hostnames:
    i = var.find(':')
    print("{} has scores of{}".format(var[:i], var[i+1:]))

Comment: but can we use this to also print the new format list in this form: [['Pam', 5, 10, 4], ['Pet', 3, 2], ['Sara', 44, 40, 50]]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution (Tested and verified):

```
hostnames = ['Pam: 5, 10, 4', 'Pet: 3, 2', 'Sara: 44, 40, 50']
hostnames = [i.split(':') for i in hostnames]
hostnames = [[ j.strip() for j in i] for i in hostnames ]
hostnames = [[int(j) if j.isdigit()==True else j for j in i] for i in 
hostnames  ]
print(hostnames)
```

Output:

```
[['Pam', '5, 10, 4'], ['Pet', '3, 2'], ['Sara', '44, 40, 50']]
```

If you want to have separate integers, you can use this code with a slight modification:

```
hostnames = ['Pam: 5, 10, 4', 'Pet: 3, 2', 'Sara: 44, 40, 50']
hostnames = [(i.replace(':',',')).split(',') for i in hostnames]
hostnames = [[ j.strip() for j in i] for i in hostnames ]
hostnames = [[int(j) if j.isdigit()==True else j for j in i] for i in 
hostnames  ]
print(hostnames)
```

Output:

```
[['Pam', 5, 10, 4], ['Pet', 3, 2], ['Sara', 44, 40, 50]]
```